# Эквивалент французскому от великого и могучего

Tags: значение-слов, ономастика, заимствования

Из Большого Энклопедического словаря на http://www.vedu.ru/bigencdic/71284/ можно узнать, что

ШАМПАР (франц. champart), терраж (франц. terrage) - в средневековой Франции (до 1789) сеньориальный побор в виде части урожая.

То, что ТИРАЖ (франц. tirage, от tirer – тянуть), а также СЕНЬОР (от лат. senior - старший), или что CHAMPART – смесь зерновых знаков, не так уж и важно. Асимметричным русским ответом, очевидно, является ОБРОК – ежегодный помещичий сбор денег (до 1883) и продуктов (до 1861) с крепостных крестьян.

Чем был оброк? Начиная с XVI века, на Руси оброк отправлялся в пользу государства владельцами земель. Оброк также был платой крестьян своему землевладельцу. Оброк тогда был тем же, чем сейчас является аренда – право пользования имуществом, которое вытекает из договора найма, но с поправкой: крестьяне во времена расцвета феодализма считались фактически собственностью феодала, и было нормой отдать «в аренду», то есть в оброк, целые деревни с живущими в них людьми. 
Вот и бабка моя, Прасковья Васильевна Полякова, подшучивала над дедом – мол, тот пришёл к ней из деревни, где все сплошь были Шампаровыми.

Предложите синоним этому французскому корню и вариант фамилии, соответственно! Просьба: МЮСЛИН не предлагать.

Answer (score 2):

Есть фамилии Собираев, Поборский, Оброков, Оброчников.

Answer (score 2):

Ну точного аналога, естественно, нет, как нет в русской истории и самого понятия, точно соответствующего французским реалиям. Феодальная система на Руси серьезно отличалась от западноевропейской.

Вот разве ясак - в его исходном понимании. Сбор с русских "вассалов" в пользу ордынского "сеньора". Но это, понятно, уровень не мелкого оброчного вассальства, а почти что межгосударственный.

Comment: Спасибо, для меня это слово новое.
Ясак (ru.wikisource.org›wiki/ЭСБЕ/Ясак) — на языке монгольских и тюркских племен обозначает дань, уплачиваемую обыкновенно натурой, главным образом пушниной, мягкой рухлядью. Перешло слово Я. в русский язык со времени завоевания Сибири.

Comment: Так только потому, что уплачивалась натурой, я и вспомнил. Без этого и не стоило упоминать, все остальное вообще очень далеко.  
(+)
Насколько понимаю, слово известно на Руси гораздо раньше. Со времен Орды. Могу ошибаться, конечно... Надо у Карамзина посмотреть, как тогда дань называлась. У меня стойкое ощущение, что именно оттуда "ясак".

Answer (score 1):

Если синонимы оброка: подать, пошлина, сбор, урок, налог, дань (а ещё ценз и чинш), то и фамилии могут быть разнообразные: Податный, Податнов, Оброчный, Оброков, Оброчин, Урочин, Урочнов, Уроков, Сборов, Сборин, Пошлинов, Налогов, Датов, Данин и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый (или уважаемая) **@shampar.** ! Вы написали в своём вопросе :" *Вот и бабка моя, Прасковья Васильевна Полякова, подшучивала над дедом – мол, тот пришёл к ней из деревни, где все сплошь были Шампаровыми.*" Я доподлинно не знаю , каким образом ваш дедушка приобрёл фамилию **ШАМПАРОВ** , но если в деревне "все сплошь" носили этакую нерусскую фамилию , то подобный феномен , скорее всего , объясним реалиями российского крепостничества . Во время оно у большинства крестьян вообще не было никаких фамилий и они , вообще , довольно туго представляли , что такое фамилия , и зачем она нужна . Фамилии крестьянам присваивали их помещики или чиновники при проведении переписей . И делалось это произвольно . Поэтому крестьяне целыми деревнями получали какую-нибудь аристократическую и  нерусскую фамилию своего владельца : Гагарины , Воронцовы , Львовкины и др . Космонавт № 1 носил княжескую фамилию Гагарин , но с голубокровными князьями Гагариными не имел абсолютно никакого родства . Вот другой пример о происхождении фамилии красного маршала В.К. Блюхера : "*Прадеда Блюхера, крепостного, отданного в солдаты и вернувшегося с Крымской войны со многими наградами, помещик назвал Блюхером по фамилии знаменитого прусского фельдмаршала времён наполеоновских войн. Прозвище со временем превратилось в фамилию.*" Я знаю также историю о том , как на Кубани во 2-й половине XIX века при проведении переписи наёмный работник , работавший у казака (переселенца с Украины) по фамилии Варава , и находившийся в этот момент в доме , был записан на ту же фамилию - Варава . Фамилии крестьянам могли присваивать по фамилии управителей или старост , а среди них типичны были немцы(=ашкеназы) и другие *нерусские* . Помните у Некрасова : "Полюбил Наташу хлебопашец вольный . / Да перечит свадьбе ***немец*** сердобольный , / *Главный управитель* . Погодим , Игнаша ..." . На одну фамилию могли записать сразу несколько человек , как говорится , попавших под руку  и ни в каком родстве не состоявших . Солдат мог получить фамилию фельдфебеля , а фабричный рабочий фамилию десятника или мастера . При этом , если у русских людей фамилий ещё не было , то у немцев , ашкеназов и других "европейцев" они уже имелись , и эти *нерусские* фамилии могли запросто заимствовать за неимением своих . Этим и объясняется большое количество *нерусских* по этимологии фамилий у вполне русских людей . Отсюда вполне возможно , что ваш дедушка , как и все прочие из его деревни , получил фамилию от своего помещика Шампарова , или помещичьего управителя Шампарова , или старосты Шампарова . В дальнейшем , деревня могла перейти к другому помещику , мог   смениться управитель или староста , так что концов уже на найти .

Comment: Спасибо, Следопыт! В тему или в точку: "Погодим , Игнаша". Отец мой - Игнатий Иванович.

Comment: @shampar. Да , пожалуйста ! Просто я хотел выразить ту мысль , что Вы зря зациклились на каком-то "эквиваленте франзузскому" . Ваша фамилия , скорее всего , никакого отношения к налогообложению крестьянства не имеет . И она необязательно французская . Она запросто может быть  немецкой , венгерской или какой другой "европейской" .